# Learning curve for kNN train set doesn't change with training size. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-nearest-neighbour

I am training several models for a binary classification task (balanced dataset).

After hyperparameter tuning, the learning curves for Logistic Regression converge to a value (no overfitting). This is not the case for kNN, as the curve for the training set has an almost constant value around 1.

**Why** is that exactly? How can I fix it?

I have attached a photo that shows this:
[image]

The code I use for plotting learning curves (influenced from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-learning-curve-py)):

```
def plot_learning_curve(estimator, name, X, y, cv = None, train_sizes = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5)):
        
   train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv = cv, n_jobs = -1, 
                                                        train_sizes = train_sizes, scoring = 'accuracy')

   train_scores_mean, train_scores_std = np.mean(train_scores, axis = 1), np.std(train_scores, axis = 1)
   test_scores_mean, test_scores_std = np.mean(test_scores, axis = 1), np.std(test_scores, axis = 1)
   . . .
```

Comment: What is the "accuracy score" in here? If it is the [accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers) than 1 seems to mean 100% correct classifications. In such case, why would you like it to change? Also, it is a bit puzzling that accuracy drops for logistic regression with more data.

Comment: Hi, Tim! Yes, it's accuracy ( (TN + TP)/(P + N) ).
Is it normal for a classifier to have 100% accuracy? Also, I thought that when we have a few instances, the classifier can fit them perfectly (high accuracy). As we add more, accuracy drops until it reaches a plateau.

the accuracy of the training curve would go to lower values since

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Without knowing more on what is your data etc. answering the "why" questions would be a guessing game.

Comment: More information about the estimators might be particularly helpful; especially, what is k?  Also, why are your plots' x-axes not the same?

Comment: Hi, @BenReiniger
what more would you like to know? k is 9 in this case (result of GridSearchCV)
Regarding the axes, notice that for LogReg I plot the last three point (starting from ~3000), while for kNN I plot all five points so the x range is larger.